# Company account & personal account in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does anyone know the differences between the company account and personal account in terms of functionality in AWS?

[The Amazon AWS help page says](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-and-activate-aws-account/):

> 7. Choose Company Account or Personal Account.
>      Note: These two account types are identical in functionality.

Seems there are no documents there to state the differences.

Because I have a client who not yet forming a company but would like to kick start the services, should we start with personal account and any possibility to transfer to company account afterwards?

Answer (score 20):

There is no difference in functionality, and if you client ever gets big enough where it matters you can always contact AWS and have them change the account configuration.

IMO, your client is not risking anything by just setting up a personal account to get going, and they may never need to switch it — just make sure that the person who sets up the account isn't someone that is likely to quit and take the account with them or hold it for blackmail — the root account credentials should be controlled by the owner or other officer of the company. All other users should have IAM accounts

Comment: Here are the docs about [IAM (AWS Identity and Access Management)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html).

Comment: Regarding functionality parity, per some AWS documentation: "Choose Personal or Professional. Note: Personal accounts and professional accounts have the same features and functions." Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-and-activate-aws-account/